# Creating .xpi file for FF

Tags: firefox, plugins

Ok so i downloaded the source code of an addon for Firefox, that was a .xpi file so i extracted that, changed some functions and now i would like to recreate a .xpi file so i can test it in Firefox.

Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: This is better suited for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) since it not specific to Ubuntu - or the Ubuntu Family at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**.xpi** files are just zip files,you can create it using the zip command.

i.e `zip /path/to/foo.xpi file1 file2 file3`

**[See the extension packaging guide here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extension_Packaging)**.

Comment: Ooh ok, i tried that before and "installed" it with Firefox (click install in the addon manager and located the file) but the addon doesn't seem to work anymore. I didn't make any major changes, just switched the mappings of 2 hotkeys...
This part of the question is solved, thanks.